# Using nls To Model

Tags: r, prediction, nls

I'm trying to use nls model certain curves that I found in a dataset. I'm not sure how I can give example data, but here are the curves as they look right now:

[image]

I tried using

```
nls( Y ~ C*(1-exp(k*X)),data=mydata, start=c(C=.3,k=-1)))
```

Even trying to specify different values for C and k, but I always got the same results:

[image]

Where the black lines are the corresponding predictions. Any idea as to how I can improve my predictions? I'm sorry, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Clearly you need to allow for the possibility of intercepts that do not depend on the coefficients of the exponential, rather than forcing all of them through zero as you currently do.  If these curves indeed have exponential forms, that will fix the problem. Why don't you try that and show us the results?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Like I said, I'm new to this, and I have only really dealt with these types of things from the diffeq side.

Comment: Unless you are sure these curves are exponentials, you might get better fits with rational functions $y = a - b / (x+c)$.

Comment: I'll try switching to that type of model, but the exponential version seemed to work out pretty well, as far as fit. Thank you so much for your help.